# If statement with cursor?

Tags: android, sqlite, if-statement, cursor

So what I am trying to do is display some information from my sqlite database into a listview. I got the basics down for that but how I display the information needs to be conditional from what the cursor gets back. Currently my cursor comes back liek this.

```
{
id_number=1234
text=testing
type=1
datetime=null
}
```

What I need to do is get the type and display according. Example:

`if (type == 1){ do code } else if (type == 2) { do a different code }`

How exactly would I parse it to do this?

Comment: How are you getting the data? Some way like this: 'Cursor c = db.rawQuery(....);'

Comment: Yes, that is how I am getting the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code to go through each of the cursor's rows:

```
Cursor c = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT id_number, text, type, datetime FROM [data base name]", null);

if(c.moveToFirst()) {

do {

    int type = c.getInt(2);

    if(type == 1) {
        //do something
    } else if (type == 2) {
        //do something else
    }

} while (c.moveToNext());

}

c.close();
```